# Touchpad not working on XPS 13

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I just got a brand new XPS 13(9350) to realize that touchpad doesn't work at all. whoa! Apparently the touchpad is working in UEFI settings, nowhere else. Windows 10's Device Manager has recognized all devices, touchpad(in HID category) and 2 ghost mice.[image]
Ubuntu disappointed too, as it doesn't work there either.
In Windows 10 settings touchpad is on. No drivers available from the DELL for touchpad or other new drivers. No touchpad software installed, default drivers are used instead by default. No hotkeys for toggling touchpad. Support is unreachable for now. It's quite a journey was to setup Windows with only keyboard functioning(external mouse does work, but didn't have it at the time).

Surprisingly nobody else has same trouble online. Exchange would be a total kill of time, as DELL takes forever to manufacture the laptop before shipping.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Touchpad also doesn't work on BIOS.

Comment: @RaniereSilva check if touchpad is connected, DELL also sent me a replacement just by one click in their troubleshooting app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having same symptoms - the issue was fixed by disassembling back cover and noticing the touchpad latch wasn't secured.