# Laptop touchpad only working in BIOS setup

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bios, kali-linux, touchpad

One day I woke my laptop from sleep and the touchpad was not working, neither the touchpad buttons nor the track point(the one that’s inside the keyboard, mostly in old dell workstation laptops). Then I rebooted my laptop in BIOS and it was working there. I thought of it to be a driver issue, so I reinstalled all drivers and I did several reboots but no luck (by drivers I mean the dell touchpad app).

I also have another OS dual booted, Kali Linux , touchpad worked great in that OS. Then I rebooted in Windows after using kali, touchpad now worked in windows also. A few hours later again the touchpad stopped after waking from sleep, I repeated the process of going into kali, working with touchpad there and then going back to windows, this workaround worked for few days, but now the touchpad is not even working in kali (working in bios though), the error it gives in kali is:

```
psmouse serio1 alps failed to enter command mode
```

I also reinstalled BIOS several times, but sometimes it works sometimes not.

Kindly help me with this issue.

My laptop specs:

```
Dell E7440 
Bios - A28 
Windows 11 Pro 
Touchpad name- PS/2 Alps Alpine
```

Comment: Now is it possible that this is a hardware problem , since it works in UEFI BIOS

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/997458/touchpad-not-working-on-xps-13?rq=1 
Pls see this

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is with drivers, because you said the touchpad works only in BIOS (but at least it works).

In my case this helped:

1. Go to Device Manager.
2. Find Keyboards -- open to see more
3. (I found there was an issue in one of the **Keyboard Devices** (!))
   Click it with right mouse button
4. Click PROPERTIES
5. Click - Driver tab
6. Click - Update Driver
7. Click - Browse my computer for drivers
8. Click - Let me pick from a list ....
9. THEN If you see multiple drivers, test which one of them works. (In my case it was the first in the list.)
10. Your touchpad should work after this.